# Google Showing Different Site's Cache

Tags: search

My Website is **(https://moviesky.in)** 
Google is showing other website's cache instead of my site.
This is other webiste: **(http://www.phs.com.tw/)**

Because of this problem Google is showing this website on top instead of my website.
And my site's SERP has also been impacted.

Please tell me that what is the problem and help me fix the problem if possible/..

Comment: Have you added your site to Google Webmasters, and checked the canonical URL, and done fetch as Googlebot?

Comment: Yes,  Everything is fine here....

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing two different sites, are you sure you don't need to clear your browser cache, or disable the cache in the network tab of chrome's developer tools?

Comment: I see the error here, so I doubt it's anything to do with OP's machine.

Comment: Hii, Paige. The First One Which is https://moviesky.in is my original website. and the second one which is : http://www.phs.com.tw/ ... this is different site. This one is being showed by Google Cache instead of my site...